# How to remove selected row from datagrid which is bind to a List?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a list that is binded to a datagrid.
xml datagrid code is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Mydg" Margin="5" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Host IP" Binding="{Binding Ip}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Host Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Port" Binding="{Binding Port}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                       <TextBlock>
                            <Hyperlink Name="hlRmv" Click="HlRmv_OnClick">Remove</Hyperlink>
                       </TextBlock>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

c#:

```
...
Mydg.ItemsSource=psList;
...
```

in the "HlRmv_OnClick" how can i remove clicked row?

Comment: I personally feel it's a tedious job to work with `DataGrid` in `wpf`. You can get the selected row by `(DataGridRow)mygrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(mygrid.SelectedItem);` where `mygrid` is the datagrid

Comment: I think you might have first load the xml into some collection and thant bind it to datagrid from code behind ? As  I am no able to see Xpath for direct XML binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
<Hyperlink Name="hlRmv" Click="HlRmv_OnClick">Remove</Hyperlink>
```

you can add tag like this

```
    <Hyperlink Name="hlRmv" Click="HlRmv_OnClick" Tag="{Binding Ip}">Remove</Hyperlink>
```

On Click you will get the Tag form the sender argument in click event

```
    private void HlRmv_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var link = sender as Hyperlink;
        var Ip = link.Tag as string;
        // your logic of removing the code here. Reload collection
        var result = psList.Where(item => item.Ip.Equals(Ip));
        psList.Remove(result);

    }
```

Comment: Thank You guys. it Works successfully